# Unable to compile Pro*c code in linux

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-pro-c

I have a pro*C file in a C project, which I am trying to compile but I don't get the C code after compile.

Here are the environment variables:

```
ORACLE_HOME           = /opt/vgi/oracle/12.1.0.2/client
```

procTest.pc file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sqlda.h>
#include <sqlcpr.h>


EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
VARCHAR uid[30];
VARCHAR pwd[30];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL INCLUDE SQLCA.H;

void main()
{
    strcpy(uid.arr,"SCOTT");
    uid.len =strlen(uid.arr);
    strcpy(pwd.arr,"TIGER");
    pwd.len = strlen(pwd.arr);

    EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO errexit;
    EXEC SQL CONNECT :uid IDENTIFIED BY :pwd;

    printf("Connected to Oracle8i using Scott/Tiger\n");

    EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
    return;

errexit:
    printf("Connection failed");
    return;


} 

/* end of main */
```

The output I get while compiling:

```
bash-4.1$ proc procTest.pc

Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Mar 27 13:22:43 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /opt/vgi/oracle/12.1.0.2/client/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

dbgc_init_all failed with ORA-48141
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


----- Call Stack Trace -----
calling              call     entry                argument values in hex
location             type     point                (? means dubious value)
-------------------- -------- -------------------- ----------------------------
skgudmp()+188        call     kgdsdst()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgeriv_int()+191     call     skgudmp()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgeriv()+19          call     kgeriv_int()         000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgeasi()+237         call     kgeriv()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcgini()+1438        call     kgeasi()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pc2main()+1207       call     pcgini()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcmain()+35          call     pc2main()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmcall()+680        call     pcmain()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmpmai()+420        call     lpmcall()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
main()+458           call     lpmpmai()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
__libc_start_main()  call     main()               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
+253                                               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?

Call stack signature: 0x4f7f9afc37164890



call stack performance statistics:
total                  : 0.000000 sec
setup                  : 0.000000 sec
stack unwind           : 0.000000 sec
symbol translation     : 0.000000 sec
printing the call stack: 0.000000 sec
printing frame data    : 0.000000 sec
printing argument data : 0.000000 sec


----- End of Call Stack Trace -----

kgepop: no error frame to pop to for error 600
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kgepop: no error frame to pop to], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kgepop: no error frame to pop to], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


----- Call Stack Trace -----
calling              call     entry                argument values in hex
location             type     point                (? means dubious value)
-------------------- -------- -------------------- ----------------------------
skgudmp()+188        call     kgdsdst()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgerinv_internal()+  call     skgudmp()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
111                                                000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgerinv()+40         call     kgerinv_internal()   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgerin()+130         call     kgerinv()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgepop()+633         call     kgerin()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgeasi()+382         call     kgepop()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcgini()+1438        call     kgeasi()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pc2main()+1207       call     pcgini()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcmain()+35          call     pc2main()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmcall()+680        call     pcmain()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmpmai()+420        call     lpmcall()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
main()+458           call     lpmpmai()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
__libc_start_main()  call     main()               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
+253                                               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?

Call stack signature: 0x6c275a0c4ae84a31



call stack performance statistics:
total                  : 0.000000 sec
setup                  : 0.000000 sec
stack unwind           : 0.000000 sec
symbol translation     : 0.000000 sec
printing the call stack: 0.000000 sec
printing frame data    : 0.000000 sec
printing argument data : 0.000000 sec


----- End of Call Stack Trace -----

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kgepop: no error frame to pop to], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kgepop: no error frame to pop to], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17998], [2], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


----- Call Stack Trace -----
calling              call     entry                argument values in hex
location             type     point                (? means dubious value)
-------------------- -------- -------------------- ----------------------------
skgudmp()+188        call     kgdsdst()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgepop()+711         call     skgudmp()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
kgeasi()+382         call     kgepop()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcgini()+1438        call     kgeasi()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pc2main()+1207       call     pcgini()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
pcmain()+35          call     pc2main()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmcall()+680        call     pcmain()             000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
lpmpmai()+420        call     lpmcall()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
main()+458           call     lpmpmai()            000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?
__libc_start_main()  call     main()               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
+253                                               000000000 ? 000000000 ?
                                                   000000000 ? 000000000 ?

Call stack signature: 0xa8f3ded765e05f1e



call stack performance statistics:
total                  : 0.010000 sec
setup                  : 0.000000 sec
stack unwind           : 0.000000 sec
symbol translation     : 0.010000 sec
printing the call stack: 0.000000 sec
printing frame data    : 0.000000 sec
printing argument data : 0.000000 sec


----- End of Call Stack Trace -----
```

I'm trying pro*C for the first time and I have no clue what is wrong here.

Comment: Use the right tags. That's apparently neither C nor C++.

Comment: i suggest you post your make file too.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds an awful lot like [Bug 20406840 : PROC 12.1.0.2 THROWS ORA-600 [17998] WHEN PRECOMPILING BY 'OTHER' USER](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=11onf2zb7f_82&_afrLoop=288087005779836)

> PROBLEM: 
>   After upgrading from 12.1.0.1 to 12.1.0.2, Pro*C throws ORA-600 [17998] 
>   when precompiling by 'Other' user, not install user of Oracle.
>
> WORKAROUND: 
>   'chmod 777 $ADR_BASE/diag/plsql' by installed user of Oralce.
>   Once directory $ADR_BASE/diag/plsql/user_ is created, 
>   Pro*C works fine even if permission of $ADR_BASE/diag/plsql reset 775.

Basically, due to a bug in 12.1.0.2, unless you're running as the user who installed Oracle, you don't have permission to create a directory and it crashes. There's a patch and a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[kfinity answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49519448/8366223) worked with small differences: chmod 777 to the diag folder, and after the first compile run it's necessary to reset it to chmod 775. [Source](http://ewaldertl.blogspot.com/2015/11/oracle-12-client-fails-to-compile.html)

Comment: I had the same stack trace and `chmod o+w /opt/oracle/database/diag` fixed it for me - allowing non-oracle users to create subfolders during compilation